# Arduino: How to pass a pointer in Program Space as parameters to a function

Tags: pointers, arduino, progmem

I am developing in Arduino, some menus to get them on the screen.
I declare the menus as tables of text strings defined in Program space as in the example.
How can I pass the pointer **Menu_Principal** as a parameter to a function?

Thank you all very much in advance.

```
const char _str_opcion_0[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú 1";
const char _str_opcion_1[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -2";
const char _str_opcion_2[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú --3";
const char _str_opcion_3[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ---4";
const char _str_opcion_4[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ----5";
const char _str_opcion_5[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -----6";
const char _str_opcion_6[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ------7";
const char _str_opcion_7[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -------8";
const char _str_opcion_8[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú --------9";
const char _str_opcion_9[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ---------A";
const char _str_opcion_A[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ----------B";
const char _str_opcion_B[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -----------C";

char* const Menu_Principal [] PROGMEM =
{
    _str_opcion_0, _str_opcion_1, _str_opcion_2, _str_opcion_3, _str_opcion_4, _str_opcion_5,
    _str_opcion_6, _str_opcion_7, _str_opcion_8, _str_opcion_9, _str_opcion_A, _str_opcion_B,
    NULL
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to a function just like the usual way you do, but you can't just use it without copying the content from the flash to memory first.

```
const char _str_opcion_0[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú 1";
const char _str_opcion_1[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -2";
const char _str_opcion_2[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú --3";
const char _str_opcion_3[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ---4";
const char _str_opcion_4[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ----5";
const char _str_opcion_5[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -----6";
const char _str_opcion_6[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ------7";
const char _str_opcion_7[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -------8";
const char _str_opcion_8[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú --------9";
const char _str_opcion_9[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ---------A";
const char _str_opcion_A[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú ----------B";
const char _str_opcion_B[] PROGMEM = "Opción Menú -----------C";

PGM_P const Menu_Principal [] PROGMEM =
{
    _str_opcion_0, _str_opcion_1, _str_opcion_2, _str_opcion_3, _str_opcion_4, _str_opcion_5,
    _str_opcion_6, _str_opcion_7, _str_opcion_8, _str_opcion_9, _str_opcion_A, _str_opcion_B,
    NULL
};

void printMenu_P(PGM_P str) {
     char buf[strlen_P(str)+1];
     strcpy_P(buf, str);
     Serial.println(buf);
 }


void setup() {
 
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();

    printMenu_P(Menu_Principal[0]);
}
```

BTW, `PGM_P` is just a macro defined by avrlib for `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response hcheung, and although your proposal works, that's not what I need to do.
  What I want is to pass the pointer as is, so that later inside the function I can read any of the options. With your option I only read the first

Comment: A pointer is a pointer, there is no difference of passing an array of an array or one element of an array. All you need to know is the data type that you are passing in. The rest are the same. `Menu_Principal` is an array of `PGM_P const` so all you need to change is `printMenu_p(PGM_P const* str)` and inside the function you can access each element with index like `str[i]`.